# Checking a checkbox on an un-rendered v-if div in vue

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

```
  <div
  v-if="!isAuto"
  class="c-input-container__input-wrapper"
  >
  <label class="c-input-container__checkable">
    <input
      id="edit-send-reminder-vue"
      type="checkbox"
      name="send_reminder-vue"
      :checked="sendReminder"
      class="c-input-container__checkable-element"
    >
```

When this Div wrapped checkbox is NOT rendered I still want the checkbox checked. Is this possible?

Comment: If the checkbox is not rendered then what difference does it make if it is checked or not? Maybe you meant you want the `sendReminder` property to be true?

Comment: If you want checkbox to be hidden but still functional – you should hide it __visually__ with `v-show`